# Large Html is displaying as Raw Html

Tags: html

I have a raw Html which I get from backend and I have saved in the javascript variable. It is huge. This is my code. I have used struts property to set them. The value is coming, I have checked the struts property value.

```
var largeHtml= "<s:property value='ss' />";
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = largeHtml;
```

When I changed that code to

```
var su = "<s:property value='ss' />";
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "<p>Test</p>";
```

It is working. But for the largehtml, It is displaying raw html. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to escape simple quotes like this :

```
var largeHtml= "<s:property value=\'ss\' />";
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: It is showing quote symbol expected. Did you check it

Comment: Its your job cheking this it was a hint to help you find out what is wrong with your code !